# Locking when possibly not needed

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a few patterns like this:

```
// rarely called
void add_to_loop() {
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

    _my_loop.push_back(some_value);
}

// called very often
void act_on_loop() {
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

    if (_my_loop.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (const auto& item : _my_loop) {
        // do stuff...
    }

    _my_loop.clear();
}
```

It seems like a bit of a waste to keep checking and locking the mutex in `act_on_loop()` when the vast majority of the time the lock will never be locked.

Are there any other patterns or classes that may help in this situation?

Comment: If there's no contention, then the overhead is small.  If you really want lockless, you could look at something like RCU.

Comment: Most lock code use a simple atomic compare and swap to see if a lock is needed before actually falling into kernel code to do the lock.  Unless you have reason to believe that this code is "slow" - optimized build with profiling, I would not worry about it.